# Backup memos from Samsung Galaxy S and restore it on a Nexus 5

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s, backup, restore, nexus-5

I just bought a Nexus 5 and I'm in the process of backing up and restore all the things I need from my old Galaxy S to my new Nexus 5. 
One of the thing I need the most is restoring the hundreds of memos from the memo app in the Galaxy S which I belive was developed by Samsung. There's no such app in the Nexus 5 so I'm looking for a way to restore those memos on the Google Keep app but with no luck.
I backed up my memos using Kies and I got a Memo.smm file. 
Is there a way to do restore it on the Nexus 5? Any other way?

Comment: Will be hard to import them in another app, as the formats are unlikely to match. What Android version is running on the Galaxy S?

Comment: it would be fine to just being able to read the .smm by converting it to a text file. Android 2.3.3

Comment: Manually sorting things out; yes, that could work. Still, no idea how to achieve that. // I was thinking of `adb backup`, but that doesn't work with 2.x. Are your devices rooted? If not, I'll have to pass this to somebody familiar with Samsung specifics.

Comment: It's not rooted but I can do that if there's no other way because I really need to keep those memos. What would I be able to do if it was rooted? I know I can use programs like Titanium but I fail to see how I can use it to restore my data on the Nexus 5.

Comment: Exactly that was what I thought about: backing up the entire app including its data with TB on the Galaxy, and then restoring it on the Nexus. Not sure if it would run there, but worth a try.

Comment: I ended up doing a Titanium backup. I then opened the memo.db file with sqllite database browser and I exported the memos to a csv. I'm now looking for a way to either import this csv to evernote or to google keep :D

Comment: That would be a separate question. I'll put the TiBu variant as answer here meanwhile.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask a question about that, I'm just trying to complete the whole process before writing an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the *Galaxy S* is rooted, you could use [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to back up the app including its data. If the *Nexus* is rooted as well, you could try restoring this backup there directly; with some luck, the entire app works there as well, and there's nothing else to do.

If not (or the restored app won't work on the *Nexus*), you could extract the app's database file from the backup, and export your memos to e.g. `.csv`. With some luck, some other Memo app will be able to import that directly; otherwise this should at least enable you to copy-paste your memos.